# Eliminate duplicates from Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have a ELK Dashboard which consumes data from kafka.
There are 4 columns in the inputted JSON data. For example columns are col1,col2,col3,col4.

There are 100 records which are fed to elastic search everyday.

Suppose i want to eliminate duplicates based on a particular column say col1 , is there a way to do on kibana dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Kibana to delete documents. 
For that you'll have to go through the delete API.

To do so you'll have to retrieve the id of the documents you want to delete and then use the api.

Or use the plugin delete-by-query to do both at the same time:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html

You can use this query to retrieve the documents with duplicates on the field col1 :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "col1",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source : https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch